My player character object can't jump in game maker, because it's a platformer
I have the basis of normal hit collision to tell when the player character can jump, but my pc can't jump. And the umbrella code is for another mechanic. I just need the pc to jump.
My code
I had help, and trying to vary the hit collision code. But it still didn't work.

Is this question still relevant, or have you made progress since this new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78320161/why-in-game-maker-when-i-try-to-add-or-modify-my-jump-height-it-doesnt-work
