Why in game maker when I try to add or modify my jump height, it doesn't work?
Whenever I try to change the equation, the jump height doesn't change at all. Only when the value added to the y constant is negative the "jump" height changes. It teleports through the platform. Also the isUmbrella is just about if it decreases or sets the standard gravity.
I tried changing the variations of how the y constant could change, at first y-= 30, y+= -30, and finally y = y - 30. And it still didn't change the jump height.
My Code


Only when the value added to the y constant is negative the "jump" height changes.

This is because in GameMaker (and most 2D engines) the Y-axis is negative.
Similair how you start a book from top-left to bottom-right. The X and Y Axis starts at top-left and goes to bottom-right by increasing it.
So in your logic, if you want to go up, you need to add a negative value to your y-position.
(If you really don't like that, then you could make a positive variable of the jump height, and make it negative in the calculation)
